# Fstream sorting - One space char not needed

Tags: c++, fstream

So, basically, I have made a pretty simple code that puts a series of numbers from an input.txt list into two output files, one for even numbers and another for uneven numbers.
It does work. The problem is that I have made it so after every number sorted to specifical file, it adds an empty space char so that the next number sorted into that list can be destingueshible from the previous one. Again, this does work too. Nonetheless, I do not need a space character after the last number sorted in each list, since there is no next number.
I tried to fix this by using the 
    if f.eof 
line, though this only work for the list into which the last number was sorted. The other list will still have the empty space character. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

fstream f;
fstream g;
fstream h;
int aux;

int main()
{
    f.open("input.txt");
    g.open("output1.txt");
    h.open("output2.txt");
    while(!f.eof())
        {
            f>>aux;

            if(f.eof())
                {
                    if(aux%2==0)
                        g<<aux;
                    else
                        h<<aux;
                }
            else
                {
                    if(aux%2==0)
                        g<<aux<<" ";
                    else
                        h<<aux<<" ";
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::istream::eof()`?  It doesn't do what you think.  You're main loop should be simply `while ( f >> aux )...`.  And as Roberto Real says in his answer, the solution is to output the separator _before_ the number, not after.  Unless you create the data first in memory (e.g. using two `std::vector<int>`), you cannot know that you've reached the end until an input fails.  (Also: why are all your variables global?  They should be local.)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the space **before** each new entry, excluding of course the first one.

Also, as noted in the comments, the condition `f>>aux` is preferred in the `while`.

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

fstream f;
fstream g;
fstream h;

int aux;

string g_sep, h_sep;

int main()
{
  f.open("input.txt");
  g.open("output1.txt");
  h.open("output2.txt");

  while(f>>aux)
    {
      if(aux%2==0)
        {
          g<<g_sep;
          g<<aux;
          g_sep = " ";
        }
      else
        {
          h<<h_sep;
          h<<aux;
          h_sep = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the loop condition is wrong, and will probably result in the last entry being processed twice.

Comment: And the code contains undefined behavior, since it uses the results of the `>>` without checking that it succeeded.  What's wrong with the usual `while ( f >> aux )...`?

Comment: Re the edit: it's more than just preferred: not checking for success after `f >> aux` is an error.  If it's a question of preferred... The variables should be local, he should check that the opens succeed, he should check for errors after closing the output files (and after the input fails), and the return value of `main` should depend on whether there was an error or not.